# How to detect and duplicate word co-occurence in a sentence in Perl?

Tags: perl, text

I have set of words that I am interested in finding the duplicates of a sentence base on the occurence of two or more words:

Example:

I want to detect 'boy' or 'boys' and 'girl' or 'girls' in the sentence, so that I can have these sets: (boy and girl), (boy and girls), (girl and boys) and (boys and girls).

Sentence:

> The **boy** is going to school with a **girl**, because the **boys** like the **girls** so much.

Sentence representation:

> The WORD1 is going to school with a WORD2, because the WORD3 like the WORD4 so much.

How can I have four (4) different forms of the sentence so that it will look like this:

**Output:**

```
The WORD1 is going to school with a WORD2, because the WORD like the WORD so much.
The WORD1 is going to school with a WORD, because the WORD like the WORD4 so much.
The WORD is going to school with a WORD2, because the WORD3 like the WORD so much.
The WORD is going to school with a WORD, because the WORD3 like the WORD4 so much.
```

**NB.**

The number of words can be dynamic from 2 or more; in this example I have 4 words.

Comment: One approach is to have a regexp for each combination. You can build each of the regular expressions from the allowable pairs of words and then concatenate all of them together with the alternation `|` operator.

Comment: @user5402: please can give me example?

Comment: Why does the output include the fifth 'WORD' without a numeric suffix?  Which of the four input words does it represent?

Comment: @ Jonathan - the 'WORD' is just a symbol I used to replacement of the other pairs of words, which is a don't care in the newly generated sentence.

Comment: I have to say I don't understand the question very much. You have a given sentence and you want to replace given words with another sets of words and form four new sentences?

Comment: @Karel - I just replace the words in bold from my sentence to give a demonstration of the duplicates of sentences I want to have. Because these are the words I'm interested i have detected.

Answer (score 1):

Use back references:

```
if ($sentence =~ m/\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1/) {
  print "repeated use of the word $1\n";
}
```

Comment: will this statement match the word pairs as i indicated in the brakets.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand the original question.

Answer (score 1):

While it still needs a lot of refinements, the following should get you started and pointed in the right direction:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Algorithm::Permute;
use Lingua::EN::Tagger;
use Lingua::EN::Inflect::Number qw(to_S);

my $text = q{The boy is going to school with a girl, because the boys
like the girls so much.};

my $tagger = Lingua::EN::Tagger->new;

my $tagged_text = $tagger->add_tags( $text );

my %nouns = $tagger->get_nouns( $tagged_text );

my %normalized;
for my $noun (keys %nouns) {
    $normalized{ to_S($noun)}{ $noun } = undef;
}

for my $nouns (values %normalized) {
    my $p = Algorithm::Permute->new([ keys %$nouns ]);

    while (my @tuple = $p->next) {
        print join(', ', @tuple), "\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
boy, boys
boys, boy
school
girl, girls
girls, girl
```